# Show (or list) things on page/document that use given style (paragraph, character, object, table or cell) in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, style

I have quite dense styling hierarchy and would like to ensure that stuff that uses those styles is set up correctly and I didn't mix something up on accident.

In Office Word there is "Select all" functionality when You right-click given style which allows You to do just that - select all text that uses given character or paragraph style.

I am looking for similar in InDesign, especially for Tables, Cells and Paragraphs/Characters.

Comment: Story Editor will show the text and the style applied to it without the actual layout. Is that what you're after? `Edit > Edit in Story Editor`

Comment: This is pretty great too. Didn't know it also works for objects other than text boxes. I've also found `Edit > Find/Change...` which allows me to search for styles. There is still a problem though - Now I can search for `Paragraph`, `Character` and `Object Styles`, but NOT `Table` and `Cell` - which is actually my biggest requirement - I'd like to be able to select all cells in table that use given cell style - is this possible? I can't find it in `Find/Change...` menu.